# https with ip can receive response in each Browser,but using domain, it can receive only in chrome?

Tags: browser, https, axios, dns

confuse me for a long time.
i use react axios in frontend and rust axum in backend deployed in remote server.

1. for ip + port:
   it works everywhere, just warning with a insecurity about my ssl that because i am transfering my domain to cloudflare.
2. for domain name + port, things go wired:
   i can telnet the <domain> <port>, but in browser except chrome, it tell me ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED and no response. actually, in chrome it just works when i toggle off the proxy switchyomega and when i open the proxy, the response of api is same as edge's situation.

seem like something wrong with dns?

1. https with ip can access whatever the browser is and whatever the proxy on or off.
2. https with domain name can only access in chrome without proxy.
3. ping/telnet can parse domain name and and telnet can access the port.
4. the header of request is different especially when i toggle the switchyomega, it change the status.
   [same api request in edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6bJA.png)
   [same api request in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmwqb.png)
   and in the firefox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxx.xxx.com:3000/xxx/xxx/xxx. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

but actually it works in ip addr.

2. only in chrome with no proxy works.
3. the callback of axios is:
   [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIBmQ.png)

Comment: I think this will be hard to answer without some clean up. It sounds like you have a locally hosted front end, a remote back end, and you are having inconsistent CORS issues. This makes sense, as a CORS failure is very context dependent with setup and I believe by browser as well. If it's always a CORS issue, try updating to just list each test 1 by 1 with the exact outcome. In general though for CORS you either need a proxy set up, need to have the server send headers allowing the request, or you need to disable the related security settings in your test browser